# Calculate Gini Importance for Boosting Trees

Tags: r, random-forest, boosting, importance

From my understanding, Gini Importance means Mean Decrease in MSE for regression objectives, and Mean Decrease in Impurity for classification objectives. Typical random forest packages like `randomForest` and `ranger` export functions to calculate it, but in `xgboost`, the function `xgb.importance` calculates "Gain", "Cover", and "Frequency" instead.

How can I get Gini Importance from an XGBoost model? A bonus would be explaining why nobody seem to care about it for boosting trees.